# Signals Emitted by Embedded Checkbox in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I currently have a setup where I am trying to embed checkboxes in a `QTableWidget`. I am setting the checkbox cells in the following way:

```
chkbox1 = QTableWidgetItem()
chkbox1.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
chkbox1.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
chkbox2 = QTableWidgetItem()
chkbox2.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
chkbox2.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
self.tblData.setItem(i, 0, chkbox1)
self.tblData.setItem(i, 1, chkbox2)
```

This seems to work fine, however I cannot seem to catch the signal emitted whenever a box is checked or unchecked. I've tried:

```
 self.connect(self.tblData, SIGNAL('itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem)'), self.updatePlot)
```

But this doesn't do anything. As a test, I've connected a button click to the same method, and it works fine, so I know it's just that I'm missing a signal.

From what I understand, `itemChanged` should be emitted any time any data is changed, and isn't changing the checkbox state changing the data?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal signature is wrong. It should be `itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *)` (Note the `*`):

```
self.connect(self.tblData, SIGNAL('itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *)'), self.updatePlot)
```

or better, use [the new style connections](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html):

```
self.tblData.itemChanged.connect(self.updatePlot)
```

Comment: +1 for new style connections. I cant imagine still trying to muck around with signatures any more.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know why I'm using the old style, I guess it's just in the code I inherited, and I got to be habit. Bad me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use ItemClicked signal instead. Since itemChanged signal is emitted when the data is changed and data is the text perhaps.

Comment: or itemSelectionChanged () seems a better idea.