# PyQt CheckBox checking in QTableWidget not working

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to read the checkstate of checkboxes in a PyQt QTableWidget with python, but when I click the checkbox I see it changing, but my code doesn't. Here's the code I'm using. Any ideas?

```
class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.load_table()

    def load_table(self):
        """Fill table with data from results"""
        self.todoTable.clear()
        result = [(0, "name", "Desc", "2014-12-07", "1"), (1, "name", "desc", "2014-12-08", "0")]
        self.todoTable.setRowCount(result.__len__())
        self.todoTable.setColumnCount(4)
        self.todoTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["State", "Date", "Name", "Description"])
        for i in range(result.__len__()):
            self.todoTable.setItem(i, 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(result[i][1]))
            self.todoTable.setItem(i, 3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(result[i][2]))
            self.todoTable.setItem(i, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(result[i][3].__str__()))
            checkItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            if int(result[i][4]) == 2:
                checkItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
                checkItem.setText("")
            else:
                checkItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                checkItem.setText("")
            self.todoTable.setItem(i, 0, checkItem)
        self.todoTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.todoTable.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)

    def item_changed(self, item):
            row = item.row()
            state = item.checkState()
            print("Current state is: {}".format(state))
            print("we're now at item in row: {}".format(row))
            if state == 2:
                print("set checked")
            elif state == 0:
                print("set unchecked")
            else:
                print("Something is not working fine here")
```

**Update:** fixed the code, updated to reflect changes

Comment: Does it help to use the `itemChanged()` signal instead of `itemClicked()` as suggested by the post http://stackoverflow.com/q/11568508/1694896?

Comment: using itemChanged() changes nothing unfortunately. The row still remains -1, and nothing changes

Comment: @phfaist Using the link you gave me I came up with the idea to pass an item to the eventhandler, it can now find the current row and the checkstate, thanks for that. However python still complains about casting a QTableWidgetItem to a QCheckBox. The program runs, but it would be nice to solve it

Comment: Why `QtGui.QCheckBox(self.todoTable.itemAt(row, 0)).setCheckState()` and not `self.todoTable.itemAt(row, 0).setCheckState()`? And also, I find it good practice to decorate your slot members with `pyqtSlot()`, precisely to check for signature issues: see http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator .

Comment: I used it because I thought you can't check the state of a QTableWidgetItem, but you can check a QCheckBox. Changing that, the eventhandler and some other small errors, I've managed to get it working. Thank you very much.